# Does srimad bhagvatam and Vishnu puranas mention shaligram worship or tulasi-jalandhar myth?

Tags: vishnu, gods, bhagavata-purana, vishnu-purana, shaligrama

Is the story of tulsi cursing Lord Vishnu found in any other puranas?
Also, is the story on the origin of shaligram only found in non-Vaishnava puranas?

Comment: Padma Purana has this story and it is Vaishnava Purana.

Comment: @TheDestroyer padma purana have stories on all gods, some chapters glorify devi other shiva other hari.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you don't believe Padma Purana is Vaishnava Purana. It is a Vaishnava Purana and so called classification of Puranas occur in Padma Purana.

Comment: @TheDestroyer padma purana is not vaishnava purana, garuda purana says that in Kali Yuga only 3 puranas are for Lord vishnu- garuda, Vishnu, bhagvatam, all other are mixed puranas.

Comment: It looks like vaishnavites appropriated salagrama worship from linga worship.  Thats why there is no vaishnavite myth behind it.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently Mahabharata mentions Lord Krishna giving importance of shaligram to yudhisthra in bhisma parva-

> Yesaya Shree Saligram strotra mantrasya
>
> Shree Bhagavan Hrishi
>
> Narayano Devata Anustup Chhandah
>
> Shree Saligram strotra mantras jape vini yogah
>
> Yudhistira Uvacha
>
> Shree Deva Deva devesa Devarchanamutamam
>
> Tat sarvam srotaumichhami Bruhime Purushotamam // 1//
>
> Shree Bhagavan Uvacha
>
> Gandakyam Chotare Tire Girirajshchya Dakshine !
>
> Dasa Yojan Vistirnam Mahachhetra Vasundhara //2//
>
> Saligramo Vabet Devo Devi Dwara Bati Vabet
>
> Uvayo Sangamo Yatra Muktistratrana Sansaya //3//
>
> Saligramo Sila Yatra Yatra dwara Bati Sila
>
> Uvayo Sangamo Yatra Mutistratrana Sansaya //4//
>
> Ajanma Krita Papanam Prayaschitam Ya Ichati
>
> Saligram Silawari Paphari Namastute //5//
>
> Akal Mritu Haranam Sarvabyadhi Binasanam
>
> Vishu Padodakam Pitwa Shirasha Dharyamyaham //6//
>
> Sankha Madhya Sthitam Toyyam Vramitam Keshavopari Angalagnam
>   Manukshanam Bramha Hatya Dikam Dayat //7//
>
> Snano Dakam Piben Nityam Chakrankita Sirot Vabam Partkshallya Sudham
>   Tatoyam Bramha Hatya Byapohati //8//
>
> Agnistomasahasnani Vajapaya Satanicha Samyak Phalama Bapnoti Visnornai
>   Vedya Vakshina //9//
>
> Naivadyayuktam Tulsim cha Misritam Vishesta Pada Jalen  
>   Vishnuyoshnati Nityam Purato Murari Prapnoti Yagyautakoti  Punyam
>   //10//
>
> Khandita Sphutita Viina Vandi Dakdhya Tathi Va Cha
>
> Saligram Sialyatra Tatra Dosho Na Vidyate//11//
>
> Namantra Pujanam Naiva Natirtham Na cha
>
> Bhabanaa Na stutir Na uppachars cha Saligram Silar cha ne //12//
>
> Bramha Hatya Dikam Papam Manobak Karya Sambhamam Shirgram Nachyati
>   Tatsarvam Saligram Silrchana//13//
>
> Nanabarna Mayam Chiva Nana Bhogena Vestitam Tathavarprasadena Laxmi
>   Kantam Balamhayam //14//
>
> Narayanorbhabo Dev Chakramadya Cha Karmana Tathavarprasadena Laxmi
>   Kantam Balamhayam//15//
>
> Krishane Sila Taneyatra Susmam Cakram Cha Drisyate   Saovagyam
>   Santatim Dhatye Sarva Sakshaym Dadhaticha//16//
>
> Vashu Devschya Chinhani Distwa Papai Pramuchyate
>
> Sridhar Sukare Bame Harivbarnatu Disyate//17//
>
> Varaha Rupenam Devam Kurmangai Rapi Chinhitam
>
> Gopadam Tatra Dissheta Varaham Vamanam Tatha //18// Pitavarnam Tu
>   Devanam Rakta Varnam Vayabhaham
>
> Narashinho Vawet Devo Mokshadam Cha Prakrititam//19//
>
> Sankha Chakra Gada Kurma Sankho Yatra Pradisyate Sankha Varnaschya
>   Devanaman Vame Devaschya Lakshanam//20//
>
> Damodarm Tatha Sthulam Madhya Chakram Pratisthitam Purna Dwarena
>   Sankrina Pita Rekha Cha Drischyate //21//
>
> Chhatrakare Vabet Rajam Vartule Cha Mahasreeya
>
> Chipite Cha MahaDukham Sulagretu Ranam Dhrubam//22//
>
> Lalate Shesha Vogastu Siropari Sukanchanam Chakrakanchanavarnanam
>   VamaDevaschya Lakshnam//23//
>
> Vamaparbe Cha Bai Cakre Krishna Varnas tu Pingalam
>   Laxinarshimhadevanam Prithak Varnastu Drisyate//24// Lamboste Cha
>   Dalidram Syat Pingale Hani Revacha
>
> Lagna Cakre Vabet Baydhir Bidare Maranamdrubam//25// Padom Dakamcha
>   Nirmalyam Mastake Dharayet Shada
>
> Visnor Dristam Vakshitabyam Tulsi Jal Misritam//26//
>
> Kalpa Koti Sahasrani Vaikunthe Basate Sada
>
> Saligram Sila Vinur Hatya Koti Vinasanam//27//
>
> Tasmat Sampujayet Dhyatwa Pujitam Chapi Sarvada
>
> Saligram Silas Trotram Yah Pathecha Dijotam//28//
>
> Sa Gakshet Parmam Sthanam Yatra Lokeshworo Hari
>
> Sarva Pap Binir Muktwa Vishnu Lokam Sa Gashati//29//
>
> Dusovataro Devanam Prithak Varnastu Disyate
>
> Ipsitam Labate Rajyam Vishnu Pooja Manukramat//30//
>
> Kotyohi Vramhahatyanamgamyagamya Ta
>
> Sarva Nasamayamti Vishu Nai Vidya Vakshanat//31//
>
> Vishno Pador Dakam Pitwa Koti Janmaghanasanam
>
> Tasma Dasta Gunam Papam Ghumou Vindupatnat//32//
>
> I chant this saligram strotra matra in front of Lord Narayan Hrishi
>
> Yudhistir asked
>
> O Lord of  lords Purushotama, I request you to tell me the saligram
>   significance
>
> Lord Replied
>
> Himalaya is situated on the bank of river Gandaki. To the south of
>   this Himalaya a big and beautiful land is situated where you can find
>   saligrams sila. This is the place where Devi Dwarabati begins. This
>   place is called Mukti Kshetra.
>
> Saligram Silas found here are very precious and significant. These
>   silas represent Lord Vishnu and the person who worship or keeps them
>   in house or washes them and drinks the water or sprinkles it on his
>   head becaomes free from all sins and is protected from untimely death.
>   That person becomes free from all sains and diseases. The most feared
>   sin Bramahatya ( Killing a Brahmin) is also washed away by worshiping
>   Saligram.
>
> The person who washes saligram with chakra everyday get rid of sins
>   like Bramahatya and if he drinks the water daily, gets the  boon equal
>   to a thousand yagyas of Lord Vishnu.
>
> The person, who worships saligram with Tulsi leaves daily, gets the
>   boon of million Yagya.
>
> Except damaged and broken Sila all silas are good to worship
>
> Without worship, without offering any sweets or without any
>   pilgrimages only chanting this saligram mantra is enough to wash away
>   the sins and for the fulfillment of all desires.
>
> There are various sizes and shapes of saligrams in which Lord Vishnu
>   is situated in different incarnations.
>
> Good Luck increases and gets satisfaction from children in every
>   aspect by worshipping saligram black in color with little chakras
>
> Person who gets the chance to look at the Vahudev sila becomes free
>   from sins. Shreedhar, Sukar,Vam, Harivarna, Varaha, Kurma and lots of
>   other type of saligram are available. some Saligramas have the marks
>   of cow feet and Narshimha Avtar.
>
> Yellowish Saligram is very auspicious as Lord himself but reddish
>   saligram is consider fearful and dangerous. Sankha, Cakra, Gada, Kurma
>   are printed on saligram. Saligram with Sankha (conch) sign is
>   considering Vamrup of lord Vishnu, where chakra in the middle is
>   consider as Damodar saligram. Saligrams of different shapes – round,
>   umbrella shape which has white lines are available; worshiping this
>   kind of saligrams gives wealth and reputation in society. Flat shape
>   saligrams create sorrow in family and saligram with sharp front side
>   create war and tension in family
>
> Saligram which have chakra around the head or on forehead and rest
>   parts and clean and smooth are very auspicious and considered as
>   Vamdeva sila. Yellowish or black in left side with chakra is consider
>   as Laxmi Narshimha sila.
>
> Worshipping long shape sila create poverty, and saligram having lagna
>   chakra creat measures diseases even death.
>
> Person who offers Tulsi leaves while worshipping saligram gets
>   salvation and can stay at Vaikuntha (Place where Vishnu live) for a
>   million years.
>
> Therefore always worship saligram, chant saligram stotra which is very
>   beneficial for mankind. We can get higher post on Vishnu Lok for doing
>   so. All sins will be destroyed and one gets Vishnulok from worshiping
>   the saligram.
>
> There are various types of description available for Lord Vishnu’s ten
>   incarnation therefore Lord’s incarnation Shree Saligram’s worship,
>   Prayer and drinking the water washes away sins of a million lives and
>   gives prosperity, wealth and reputation so Saligram should be
>   worshiped.

Garuda purana too mentions about shaligram, but the story of vrinda-tulsi is not found in itihasas and vaishnava puranas.

http://www.salagram.net/sstp-GarudPuran1.html

The story of vrinda and tulsi is only found in shaiva puranas, which well most vaishnavas would reject, also the story is clearly shruti virodhi as Vishnu is described as fully celibate in Vedas and satwik  puranas, so this story doesn't gel out with the character.

Answer (score 0):

Jalandhar is hinted in Mahabharata Anushasana Parva which is in total sync with Shiva Maha Purana.

**The Mahabharata.**
**Book 13: Anusasana Parva.**
**[SECTION XIV](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13a014.htm#fn_39).:->**

> *O Kesava, in days of yore, upon the body of that great cause of universal affliction.  **The discus which thou bearest, O sinless one, was given unto thee by Mahadeva after he had slain a Daitya that was proud of his strength and used to live within the waters.** That discus, blazing with energy and like unto fire, was created by the great god having for his device the bull. Wonderful and irresistible in energy it was given unto thee by that illustrious god. In consequence of its blazing energy it was incapable of being gazed at by any person save Siva the wielder of Pinaka. It was for this reason that Bhava (Siva) bestowed upon it the name of **Sudarsana.** From that time the name Sudarsana came to be current in all the worlds.*

Jalandhar was the son of Samudra deva (Ocean) and a Shivamsha, whom Lord Shiva had killed with Sudarshan Chakra.

**Sri Shiva Maha Puranam ([2.5:5:24:45-50](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226165.html)).:->**

> ***45. Śiva held in his hand the wheel Sudarśana which he had made with his toe and got ready to kill him.***
>
> *46. Lord Śiva hurled the discus Sudarśana which resembled a crore suns and the fire of dissolution.*
>
> ***47. Blazing the heaven and the earth, the discus hit Jalandhara and severed his head with wide gaping eyes.***
>
> *48. The body of the **son of the ocean** fell on the ground from the chariot making the earth resonant. The head too fell. There was a great hue and cry.*
>
> *49. His body fell in two halves like the mountain of collyrium split by the thunderbolt and hurled in the ocean.*
>
> *50. The whole universe was filled with his terrible blood O great sage, the entire earth became deformed.*

Again, the above answer i think given by you only, also mentioned about the importance of the Shaligrama Shila in Mahabharata and as we all know Itihasa>>>Purana.

I hope this clarifies your queries.